# Can a WinHTTP server handle clients in seperate thread just like Winsock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, winsock, winhttp

#### Objective

I'm writing an HTTP server in C++17.

For the sake of the discussion, I reduce the requirements to:

1. Simple HTTP Echo Server.
2. Expects multiple clients.
3. Clients constantly send simple `GET` requests.
4. Handle each client in a separate thread.
5. Respond by `200 OK`

#### Winsock

I read this example: [Winsock Server Source Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-server-code).

I understand how to adjust this example to answer the requirements (similar to what was [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37285774/1798187)):

1. Create a `std::thread` that listen for clients
2. When a client is accepted, create a new thread for the client and pass the new `SOCKET`.

#### WinHTTP

I also want to experiment with `WinHTTP` as well. So, I read this: [HTTP Server Sample Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/http-server-sample-application)
.

But, I got a bit lost trying to apply the same "tactic" as before. There is no equivalent WinHTTP function to Winsock's [`accept()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-accept) that will allow me to create a thread per client.

#### Question

Assuming the approach I intend to apply in `Winsock` is valid, is there a similar approach to make `WinHTTP` handle each connection/client in a separate thread?

Comment: Did you read the [HTTP Server API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/http-api-start-page) documentation yet?  For what you are attempting to do, I would suggest using the API in [*asynchronous* mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/http-completion-routines), so that you can associate an `OVERLAPPED` struct with each request, and then spin up multiple threads to service the I/O completions as needed.

Comment: No, you are not going to be able to use a one-thread-per-client model in WinHTTP like with WinSock. But on the other hand, if you need to deal with a lot of clients simultaneously, a one-thread-per-client model is not the best choice to begin with.  WinSock can do asynchronous I/O, too.